# Program/library to generate many technical indicators given a series of stock prices

Tags: software, technicals

I have a time series (vector) representing the evolution of a stock price over time. I am looking for a program/library that can generate a matrix containing as many technical indicators as possible. Which publicly available program/library can do that?

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- http://qr.ae/TbcrXL

Comment: Undoubtedly you're aware of that while some prominent academics (eg. [Andrew Lo](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/0022-1082.00265/full) of MIT) have written papers taking technical analysis seriously, there's a whole bunch of snake oil around the technical analysis world. When reading, I'd have my bullshit detector set to maximum.

Comment: downvote explanation welcome

Comment: meta: [Why 3 downvotes on this question?](https://quant.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1544/2183)

Comment: and [When should we close a question as "seeking assistance in developing a trading strategy"?](https://quant.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1546/2183)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://qr.ae/TbcrXL:

Phil Newton's answer:

> Most modern charting packages can do this.
>
> - Meta trader.
> - Ninja trader.
> - Multi Charts.
> - Tradestation.

Naoya Yamaguchi's answer:

> And Ninja trader is free. You can also program more indicators into it, using C#. This means a great collection of .NET assemblies, including Deep Learning assemblies like Accord, are available to you, too!

Answer (score 1):

I did the search by myself some time ago and couldn't find much that is readily available (in the sense that you can directly use it in a Python program, say). The closest I found find is the following library:

[TA-Lib : Technical Analysis Library](http://www.ta-lib.org/index.html)

It's a bit dated, however, with the latest release being published in 2007.